# For each sender ID, GCM allows 1000 connections in parallel

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

Refer https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#connecting

I want to have a XMPP based server for GCM. I am unable to understand 
"For each sender ID, GCM allows 1000 connections in parallel" 
Here What does connection mean ?

```
is it the connection which my CCS server will make with GCM server ?
is it the connection that each device (ios/android/crome) will make with GCM server ?
```

Answer (score 0):

it simply means, your app (Sender) can not send more than 1000 push notification at a time from you server side to Google Cloud Message Server.

The solution is that if you have more than 1000 users of your app, you can send it in batches instead of attempting to send to all at one. just sending in chucks of 1000.

Comment: when multicast messaging is not supported with CCS - XMPP, how is it even possible to send 1000 users in batch ? I think your answer is valid for HTTP servers only